# Nonlinear Klein Gordon equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, klein-gordon-equation

For the Klein Gordon nonlinear equation,

$$ u_{tt}- \Delta u +f(u)=0,$$

how could I use Noether's theorem to prove that there is a conserved quantity? I.e.,

$$ (\Pi _{k} )_{t} - \rm div(j_{k})=0 $$
for  $k=0,1,2,3$, where

$$ \Pi _{k} = \int _{R^{3}}p(x,y,z,t)dv $$
is the density of four-momentum.

Comment: Write down a Lagrangian density producing that equation and notice that it can be chosen to be invariant under space-time translations...

Answer (score 1):

Define $F(u):= \int_0^u f(s) ds$, so the equations for the field $u(t,\vec{x})$ can be re-written as $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}-\Delta_{\vec x} u + \frac{dF}{du}=0\::$$ If defining $${\cal L}:= \frac{1}{2}(-\partial_t u\partial_t u + \nabla u \cdot \nabla u) + F(u)\:.$$ this Lagrangian density leads to your field equations.

Moreover, as you can directly see, ${\cal L}$ is invariant under spatial translations, since it does not explicitly depend on $\vec{x}$. It is also invariant under temporal translations, because it does not explicitly depend on $t$. Therefore you can apply Noether's theorem obtaining four conserved quantities. They are the four integrated "charges" associated with the stress-energy tensor, i.e. the components of the total four-momentum.

Comment: i know that the equation is invariatn under traslation but what exactly the $ J_{k} $ are ?

Comment: Consider the stress energy tensor $T^{a}_b = \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \frac{\partial u}{\partial x^a}}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^b} - \delta^a_b {\cal L}$, that is conserved due to Noether's theorem in view of translational invariance. $J_a = \int_{\mathbb R^3} T^0_a d^3x$, $a=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: i understand this thanks :D but from this how could i reach to the final equation $ (\Pi_{k} )_{t}+divJ =0 $

Comment: Sorry, there is some mess with my and your notations. **From now on** I use only the notations you adopted in your question. Using $T_b^a$ as defined above: $\Pi_k = T^0_k$ and $j^i_k = T^i_k$, $i=1,2,3$. Noether's theorem proves that $\sum_{a=0}^3\partial_a T^a_k=0$. Recasting it using your notations, you find: $(\Pi_k)_t + div(j_k)=0$. I do not understand your last identity you wrote in your question. It is not coherent with the previous identities.